# Bluetooth Find Devices

Tags: bluetooth

I building a application that contains bluetooth functionality. Everything works find and to test it.

The question is, is there any way I can simulate a devices bluetooth so that my application can discover it. I need to test it for around 30 devices bluetooth, seems like unreasonable for me to go find 30 real devices.

If someone could point me to an existance app or article to refer would be helpful.

Comment: I afraid you can't. However there is no problem to find 30 or more devices. Visit any public place (shop or something). I am sure - there are lot of devices.

Comment: alright, thank you for your input